# How to download a file from a URL in OS X app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

How do I download a file from a URL in an OS X app?  I am a Unix C and Perl programmer new to Objective C.  I've been reading the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FURLLoadingSystem%2FURLLoadingSystem.html&ei=9FfZVOT-OoygNqmUgKAJ&usg=AFQjCNFikjg4n31ZzTHQ4V96j_Y_w2H73w&sig2=JpIQDrRNb-kwFxVVPUdGCA&bvm=bv.85464276,d.eXY), which suggests NSURLSession for new OS X apps.  So I'd prefer a solution with NSURLSession or NSURLSeesionDownloadTask, but am open to NSURLDownload or other solutions.

My first attempt was based an example found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F67081%2Fcookbook-using-nsurlsession&ei=tgvZVNOMOtHSoASQmoGABQ&usg=AFQjCNH3yQnmXiGd9-C-P_Sjny-tK2dBGA&sig2=h6P2mVldV2lsq_1Ryt5hFg&bvm=bv.85464276,d.cGU)

```
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask =
        [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
         downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfFile]
         completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

             // move tmp file to permanent location
             NSLog(@"Done...");
             NSLog(@"Location:   %@", location);
             NSLog(@"Response:   %@", response);
             NSLog(@"Error       %@", error);

             NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
             BOOL fileCopied = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:[location path] toPath:[appDir stringByAppendingString:@"/demo.pdf"] error:&error];
             NSLog(fileCopied ? @"File Copied OK" : @"ERROR Copying file.");
            }];
    [downloadTask resume];
    NSLog(@"Now we are here");
```

The example code (and my version) don't have a separate delegate.  The completionHandler is "in line".  (Not sure if that's the correct terminology).  I assume this code would be executed AFTER the download task completes. Is that correct?

My second attempt was based on the "Downloading Files" section of the URL Programming Guide:

```
    // PDF file Download, try #2
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *appDir = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *pdfFile = @"https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppDistributionGuide.pdf";

    // Configure Cache behavior for default session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration
    *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSString *cachePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory()
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/pdfDownload.cache"];
    NSLog(@"Cache path: %@\n", cachePath);
    NSURLCache *myCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity: 16384
                                                        diskCapacity: 268435456 diskPath: cachePath];
    defaultConfigObject.URLCache = myCache;
    defaultConfigObject.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
    defaultConfigObject.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 100;
    defaultConfigObject.timeoutIntervalForResource = 100;

    // Create a delegate-Free Session
    NSURLSession *delegateFreeSession =
        [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject
                                      delegate: nil
                                 delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [[delegateFreeSession downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfFile] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        // move tmp file to permanent location
        NSLog(@"Done...");
        NSLog(@"Location:   %@", location);
        NSLog(@"Response:   %@", response);
        NSLog(@"Error       %@", error);

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        BOOL fileCopied = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:[location path] toPath:[appDir stringByAppendingString:@"/demo.pdf"] error:&error];
        NSLog(fileCopied ? @"File Copied OK" : @"ERROR Copying file.");
    }] resume];

    sleep(10);
    NSLog(@"After sleep...");
```

In both cases, code execution never gets to the NSLog statements that are part of the completionHandler.  I have breakpoints set in the simulator, and never get there.  How do I create a simple "delegate free" file download method?

Since I am writing a "command line" OS X app, I don't have a UIViewController, or other existing structure for delegates.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?  I don't need a download progress bar, etc., just a "pass/fail" status.

Also, my example here is for a single PDF file.  My app has an array of URLs that I'd like to download.  I don't need to download them in parallel.  Could I reuse a single NSURLSession in a loop?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: If the problem is that your request is timing out, you may not be giving it enough time to fail and print an error message. It depends on what your timeout is set to (it may be the default value).

Comment: @ZevEisenberg: I added a second code fragment with some detailed configuration, including high timeout values.  Still never gets to the completionHandler.  I assume this should work in the simulator, correct?

Comment: What simulator? You said it's an OS X app.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg: The Xcode simulator.  I'm targeting OS X, but for now, I'm still running in the simulator.

Comment: Xcode simulator = OSX

Comment: Your program is exiting before the download is finished (that PDF is a large file). You probably need to block (or do something on) the main queue while you wait. Look into `dispatch_group` and `dispatch_group_notify`. I played with it, but I haven't used GCD them in the context of command line apps.

Comment: Excellent!  That helps a lot!  I should have chosen a smaller PDF for testing.  Never thought it was an issue.  Code now executes in the completion handler.  I'll look into process blocking, and then see if I can figure out why the larger PDF caused an issue.  The PDFs I'm dealing with are in the 20-40 MB range, so I'll need to be able to handle files of that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to close this once I got the solution.  As Zev pointed out, the PDF file I chose was large, and needed more time to download.  The 10 second 'sleep(10)' didn't provide enough time to download the 39 MB file.

Notifications should be used to indicate when the completionHandler finishes.  But for now, I am using a simple polling loop.  I changed sleep(10); to

```
int  timeoutCounter = 60;
while ((timeoutCounter > 0) && !downloadDone) {
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"Timout: %d", timeoutCounter--);
}

if (!downloadDone) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Timeout occurred before file completed downloading");
}
```

This requires the declaration of downloadDone to allow the completionHandler block to set it:

```
    __block BOOL downloadDone = FALSE;
```

After the NSFileManger moves the file, this semaphore must be set:

```
     downloadDone = TRUE;
```

Thanks again for the help Zev!

I'm still working on error checking/handling, but here is the full corrected method:

```
+ (NSError *)           downloadFileAtURL:(NSString *)fileURL
                                toDir:(NSString *)toDir
                              timeout:(NSNumber *)timeout {

// completion handler semaphore to indicate download is done
__block BOOL downloadDone = FALSE;

// same PDF file name for later
NSString *downloadFileName = [fileURL lastPathComponent];
NSString *finalFilePath = [toDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:downloadFileName];
NSLog(@"PDF file name: '%@'", downloadFileName);
NSLog(@"Final file path: '%@'", finalFilePath);

// Configure Cache behavior for default session
NSURLSessionConfiguration
*defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSString *cachePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory()
                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/downloadFileCache"];
NSLog(@"Cache path: %@\n", cachePath);
NSURLCache *myCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity: 16384
                                                    diskCapacity: 268435456 diskPath: cachePath];
defaultConfigObject.URLCache = myCache;
defaultConfigObject.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy;
defaultConfigObject.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 100;
defaultConfigObject.timeoutIntervalForResource = 100;

// Create a delegate-Free Session
//      delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSession *delegateFreeSession =
[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject
                              delegate: nil
                         delegateQueue: nil];

[[delegateFreeSession downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    
    // move tmp file to permanent location
    NSLog(@"In the completion handler...");
    NSLog(@"Location:   %@", location);
    NSLog(@"Response:   %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Error       %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Location path: %@", [location path]);
    
    // Verify temp file exists in cache
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if ( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[location path]]) {
        NSLog(@"File exists.  Now move it!");
        
        error = nil;
        BOOL fileCopied = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:[location path]
                                               toPath:finalFilePath
                                                error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        NSLog(fileCopied ? @"File Copied OK" : @"ERROR Copying file.");
    }
    downloadDone = TRUE;
    
}] resume];

// use timeout argument
int  timeoutCounter = [timeout intValue];
while ((timeoutCounter > 0) && !downloadDone) {
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"Timout: %d", timeoutCounter--);
}

if (!downloadDone) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Timeout occurred before file completed downloading");
}

NSError *error = nil;
return error;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `sleep()`. Run the [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) or `dispatch_main()`. If you want a timeout, use `NSTimer` (requires running the run loop) or `dispatch_after()`. A timer can be invalidated, which is needed if your program is going to keep running doing other stuff. If you're just going to exit when the download completes, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the run loop and dispatch_main() suggestions, Ken.  I am new to Objective C, so the goal of this question was to understand NSURLSession, and the completion handler.  I have added the Threading Programming Guide to my list of docs I need to read.  I appreciate the comment!